# detect if Facebook is logged into Facebook when opening Facebook page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to detect whether the user is logged in into Facebook account when opening a Facebook tab? I need to display a message "login to Facebook and come back, to see the content".

NB I want to do this server side.

Relying plainly on *page liked == false* and *page admin == false* is naive. At the same time, `signed_request` is always sent the same, regardless user login status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look in this article:

https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Here You'll find info about detect if user is ogged in at facebook, google, twitter..

Other solution is:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: There is a server side solution, but just as useful as the client side version. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/